# Create Planner Group and Plan through Graph API, both show up in Planner Hub

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm creating a new group and a new plan where the new group is the owner of the plan.

Unfortunateley, both of them show up in my Office 365 Planner Hub. Is this the desired behaviour? I don't want the group to show up in the Planner Hub.

Comment: This isn't really a "programming" question but yes, this is by design. Your Planner Hub will show all of the "plans" you have access to (including group plans you have access too).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. It might have been a programming question in case I had done something wrong in my programming.